# How to delete user-created templates?

Tags: templates

I've created some templates, but I'd like to delete some of my old ones. I can't figure out how to do so. I'm using TeXstudio on Mac OS. I'm able to access the Library files for TeXshop and TeXworks, but the only files in the template folder are the standard ones built in. I can't seem to find them in any other folders. Any tips or ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Without more specific information (How you exactly created the templates? How you exactly access the templates? In which OS?) that question is off-topic as more or less is like " I lost files in my hard disk"  and the answer only can be "search a method to search your files in  your unknown OS" (for linux for instance, `locate mytemplate`) but as is is not a problem related with of TeX and friends`.